# How to make ctrl-c work in `timeout` command work in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

How to make this interruptable with ctrl-c?

```
# Makefile
foo:
    timeout 1m bash -c "while true; do date; sleep 1; done"
```

GNU Make 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run `timeout` with the `--foreground` option; see the man page:

```
   --foreground
          when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
          allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in  this
          mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

Since you're running `timeout` from inside a makefile, which is not *directly from a shell prompt*, you need this to allow it to receive TTY signals (like CTRL-C).

Comment: @guettli Remember to accept the answer so MadScientist gets internet points!

Comment: it is useful in Makefile.