# timeout runs on Makefile different than bash

Tags: bash, makefile, timeout

I have a Makefile with such a rule. `spike_bin` created by a flag either `timeout 10 /opt/riscv/bin/spike` or `/opt/riscv/bin/spike`. It runs the version without timeout but not the other one.

```
shell := /bin/bash # this doesn't solve the problem

debug/%.raw_golden.log: debug/%.spike.script
    $(spike_bin) -d --debug-cmd=$<  $(spike_flag) --log=$@ $*
```

The error out is below:

```
timeout 1 /opt/riscv/bin/spike -d --debug-cmd=debug/csr_basic.s.spike.script  --log-commits --log=debug/csr_basic.s.raw_golden.log csr_basic.s.riscv
make: *** [Makefile:108: debug/csr_basic.s.raw_golden.log] Error 124
```

Error 124 is the code that `timeout 1 sleep 2; echo $?` gave 124 too.
when I run the command that Makefile run `timeout 1 /opt/riscv/bin/spike -d --debug-cmd=debug/csr_basic.s.spike.script  --log-commits --log=debug/csr_basic.s.raw_golden.log csr_basic.s.riscv` It successfully completed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: using `/usr/bin/timeout` instead of `timeout` is not solved the problem too

Comment: Have you tried running `timeout 1 true` inside the makefile? Does it timeout, or does it complete successfully?

Comment: @Socowi it was completed successfully.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081652/17152928 this solution is worked on my problem too. I mean adding `--foreground` solves the problem. Since I didn't know the actual issue and why it `--foreground` solved my problem, I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem, and linked the answer. I closed this question as a duplicate for you.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplication because the answer and the question I post are different from what I asked(I think). @Socowi

Comment: If it is a general flow of stackoverflow it doesn't matter of course.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I thought I'd make your linked solution more visible by marking it as a duplicate, but I forgot that this also prevents users from answering here. I'd say, the changes are slim, but maybe someone comes along and *explains* why the linked solution (to another problem) works for your problem *too*. I reopened the question.